# Flash/Flex: play embedded AAC audio?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, embed, aac

Is it possible to *play* an *embedded* AAC file in Flash/Flex somehow? I know you can playback embedded MP3 files, but I hear that [you can't do that with AAC](http://kaioa.com/node/81). Anyone know any sneaky ways to get around this?

By way of illustration, here's come code.

```
[Embed(source='../../audio/music02.m4a', mimeType="audio/aac")]
private static const __ExampleMp4File:Class;
public var myMp4Sound:Sound = new __ExampleMp4File();

public function EmbeddedAudioTest()
{
  myMp4Sound.play();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.  If you convert the audio file to video with just an audio track, then you can play it.

This does seem like a silly oversight in the player since it has support for playing embedded sound and support for AAC embedded in video.

Comment: Oh, so you _can_ play [Embed]-ed video files?! That sounds like a compromise I'm very willing to make. Can you post code to illustrate?

Comment: Hey Sam, just a wee nudge ... you can/can't play embedded video files?

Comment: @aaaidan, yes, you can `[Embed]` a video and play it.